# Pentaho Data Integration Installation Problem in macOS 10.15.4

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm attempting to install PDI 9 and keep on getting below error from the terminal.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I currently have the following installed.

- pdi-ce-9.0.0.0-423 (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/)
- jre-8u241-macosx-x64 (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jre8-downloads.html)

I tried a workaround found [here](https://community.hitachivantara.com/s/question/0D52S00007nb3dmSAA/jdk1301-and-jdk1302-not-working-for-pdi-9) by removing below line from the spoon.sh file.

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS
```

The spoon.sh file runs, however, the application immediately closes after pulling up. Below shows first few lines that include a number of warning messages.

```
DEBUG: Using value (/Users/juanflorencioferrer/Downloads/data-integration/Data 
Integration.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../) from calling script
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.KettleURLClassLoader (file:/Users/juanflorencioferrer/Downloads/data-integration/launcher/../lib/kettle-core-9.0.0.0-423.jar) to field java.net.URLClassLoader.ucp
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.KettleURLClassLoader
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
20:03:06,639 INFO  [KarafBoot] Checking to see if org.pentaho.clean.karaf.cache is enabled
20:03:06,801 INFO  [KarafInstance]
...
2020/04/14 20:03:36 - Spoon - Spoon  has ended.
stopping
[Process completed]
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5):

It appears I needed to uninstall an existing JDK 11 version and replace it with JDK 8. Link below for instructions.

https://www.codevoila.com/post/78/how-to-uninstall-or-remove-jdk-in-mac-os-x

Comment: I had the same problem, thanks. In my case the native version that came on the system itself was JRE, and Pentaho only runs on JDK.

Answer (score 0):

would like to share what solved the PDI installation to me,
on a mac running MacOS Catalina V.10.15.7:

- [PDI 8.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Pentaho%208.2/client-tools/pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342.zip/download) + [java version "1.8.0_321"](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8-mac)

After installing and trying to run thru command line, the Data Integration window wouldn't show up, so I found out that's because it needs to have the [SWT file] updated(https://community.hitachivantara.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/view-question?ContributedContentKey=0cbaf1aa-079e-435c-a57e-5c2a505b02de&CommunityKey=e0eaa1d8-5ecc-4721-a6a7-75d4e890ee0d&tab=digestviewer).

Following the steps on the post, there's different versions to choose from. I tested many of them and "org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64-3.116.100.jar" is the one that worked on my pc.

Also, after loading the main window, the texts next to the icons would appear "blank", but that was because I had "dark mode" (Appearance, on General Settings) enabled on my system. So, after changing it back to "Light mode" and restarting PDI, everything looked "normal".

Hope that could be of some help and save you some time!

[]